# How get the permalink of a WordPress multisite shared post

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

In WordPress multisite setup each network site has its own wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables. So if I want to share a post from one wp network site to another I can use wpdb class to query posts from other network sites or I can use the switch_to_blog() WPMU function

```
<?PHP
$new_blog = 2;
switch_to_blog($new_blog);
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink($post->ID) ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title ?></a>
<?php
restore_current_blog();
?>
```

the get_post_permalink() function will return the link to the shared post of the network site.

My question is how can I get a permalink of the shared post pointing to current's blog domain making it look like the post is hosted on the current blog.

All the plugins I found that share content across multiple WPMU sites duplicate and syndicate posts. I'm looking for a solution that would enable me to share some content and making it look like it has it's own url.

Comment: I do not have experience with multi sites but could you grab the site using `get_site_url()` and then do a `str_replace` with the url from `get_post_permalink`?

Comment: This is a good idea but once I do that I'll create a link that doesn't exist. What I'm trying to achieve is to make WordPress to pull content from other than default tables in the back end. I could use one wp_post and wp_postmeta table and configure every multisite to use it this way all posts would have URLs on all network sites. Again this is not desirable. I need to share some posts of a certain category only

Comment: that's a totally different bag of worms not sure how you would go about doing that without duplicating the post

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following, as @David Nguyen suggested.

```
<?php
    $new_blog = 2;
    switch_to_blog($new_blog);  

    $my_permalink = str_replace( home_url() . '/', network_home_url(), get_post_permalink($post->ID) );
?>
<a href="<?php echo $my_permalink ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title ?></a>
<?php
    restore_current_blog();
?>
```

Comment: I did exactly what you recommended

what that does is to creates an URL to a post on a different domain which doesn't exist.

Comment: I must not be reading your original question correctly. What I was assuming is that you are wanting to take a post permalink, for example: `http://network.site.tld/post-name` and change it to `http://site.tld/post-name`

Comment: I am pretty sure his goal was to show a post from "blog_1" on "blog_2" and have the permalink not link back to blog_1 but actually show the post on blog_2